# Why does .bind(this) fix a setState rendering issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-modal` and while doing so, I came across an issue where I was setting the state while the application was rendering. How come the following piece of code with `.bind(this)` is okay:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: false
    }
}

openModal() {
    this.setState({
        open: true
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}>Open Modal</button>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.open}>
                <h1>I am a modal</h1>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but this is not:

```
...
<button onClick={this.openModal()}>Open Modal</button>
...
```

I received a warning about `setState(…): Cannot update during an existing state transition`, and if anyone can explain this to me that'd be great.

Comment: You need to bind in ES6 classes because they aren't autobound: http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Answer (score 2):

I'm believe that when you're writing `onClick={this.openModal()}` instead of `onClick={this.openModal}` you're actually calling the function during the render (i.e. the "state transition"). 
This function is changing the state via the `setState` call. Changing the state inside a render is an anti-pattern. That's why you get the warning.

That being said, you need `.bind(this)` when it comes to callbacks, because you're using the `this` keyword inside your method. Usually, and here in particular you want `this` to point to the component. But Javascript is funny in that `this` depends on who's calling the function, and when you pass it like that (as the `onClick` callback), it's probably not gonna be the component who's gonna be calling it. So to make sure `this` is pointing to the right thing, you `bind` it.